# Able to locate elements manually in Appium Inspector using xpath but when I run my code I get error as element not located for same xpath

Tags: macos, appium

I am able to locate elements manually in Appium Inspector using xpath but when I run my code I get error as element not located for same xpath. The xpath I am using is:

```
public By _loginEID = new ByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='userNameInput']");
```

Below is the error detail:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: //android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='userNameInput']
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
System info: host: 'AMAC02TN0ESG8WL', ip: '192.168.43.219', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{appPackage=com.accenture.globalBuilding, statBarHeight=63, noReset=true, viewportRect={top=63, left=0, width=1080, height=1731}, deviceName=emulator-5554, platform=LINUX, deviceUDID=emulator-5554, chromedriverExecutable=/Users/karthik.g.suvarnaaccenture.com/eclipse-workspace/Places_App_Regression 2_OldJun8/chromedriver/chromedriver, desired={appPackage=com.accenture.globalBuilding, appActivity=com.accenture.globalBuilding.MainActivity, chromedriverExecutable=/Users/karthik.g.suvarnaaccenture.com/eclipse-workspace/Places_App_Regression 2_OldJun8/chromedriver/chromedriver, noReset=true, appWaitActivity=com.accenture.globalBuilding.MainActivity, platformName=Android, deviceName=Pixel2}, platformVersion=10, webStorageEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=Android, deviceApiLevel=29, deviceManufacturer=Google, deviceScreenSize=1080x1920, networkConnectionEnabled=true, warnings={}, appWaitActivity=com.accenture.globalBuilding.MainActivity, databaseEnabled=false, appActivity=com.accenture.globalBuilding.MainActivity, pixelRatio=2.625, locationContextEnabled=false, deviceScreenDensity=420, deviceModel=Android SDK built for x86}]
```

Answer (score 0):

While constructing the xpath, use the complete resource-id, inclusive of the app package name.

Here, you are using 'userNameInput' as the resource-id.

Try using something like this -

`//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='com.accenture.globalBuilding:id/userNameInput']`